# Row-wise multiplication of selected columns with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

What is the way to perform row-wise multiplication of all columns selected from a daraframe.
Below Mult columns is created explicitly by saying what variables to multiply.

What if I selected different columns? What code needs to be in mutate so it will multiply all columns selected before? NOTE: number of selected columns will not always be three.

example:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, qsec, disp) %>% 
  mutate(mult = hp * qsec * disp)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way would be using `rowProds` from package `matrixStats`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, qsec, disp) %>% 
  mutate(mult=rowProds(as.matrix(.)))
```

But I am sure there is a more elegant way without using another package.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you very much. Even though I know `matrixStats` package I kind of forget to try it :D. Your solution is elegant enought :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Reduce` -

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, qsec, disp) %>% 
  mutate(mult = Reduce(`*`, .))
```

Or `rowwise` with `prod` -

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, qsec, disp) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(mult = prod(c_across()))
```